# How to get all sublists possible from a list by removing one element in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a list `List(1,2,3,4)` and want all the sublists obtainable by removing one element:

```
List(2,3,4)
List(1,3,4)
List(1,2,4)
List(1,2,3)
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you meant "leave each *position* in the List out", then:

```
val x = List(1,2,3,2)

x.indices.map(i => x.take(i) ++ x.drop(i+1))
// List(2, 3, 2)      // skipped index 0
// List(1, 3, 2)      // skipped index 1
// List(1, 2, 2)      // skipped index 2
// List(1, 2, 3)      // skipped index 3
```

If you meant "leave each *unique element* in the List out", then:

```
x.distinct.map(e => x.filter(_ != e))
// List(2, 3, 2)      // filtered out 1s
// List(1, 3)         // filtered out 2s
// List(1, 2, 2)      // filtered out 3s
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, I think I figured out a slightly simpler version though.

Answer (score 3):

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4).combinations(3).toList
```

Or, more generically,

```
list.combinations(list.size - 1) // use the Iterator -- combinations can be huge in size
```

Comment: How come `List(1,2,3,2).combinations(3).foreach(println)` doesn't print out `2,3,2`?

Comment: @GarrettHall because ordering is inconsequential when finding `combinations`. `List(2, 3, 2)` is identical to `List(3, 2, 2)` or `List(2, 2, 3)` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
val x = List(1,2,3,4)
x.map(i => sizes - i)
```

Comment: Did you mean `x` instead of `sizes`?  If so, this won't work for `x = List(1,2,3,2)`.  Also it uses `-`, which is deprecated.