# Best way to compute a function on each element with incremental shadowing of element in these collection

Tags: scala, collections, dictionary, slice

What is the best way to compute a function on each element in a collection with an incremental shadowing of each element, like this simple example :

```
val v = IndexedSeq(1,2,3,4)

v.shadowMap{ e => e + 1}

shadow 1: (3,4,5)
shadow 2: (2,4,5)
shadow 3: (2,3,5)
shadow 4: (2,3,4)
```

I think first to `patch` or `slice` to make this, but perhaps there is a more better way to do that in pure functional style ?

Thanks
Sr.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603733/how-to-get-all-sublists-possible-from-a-list-by-removing-one-element-in-scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def shadowMap[A,B](xs: Seq[A])(f: A => B) = {
  val ys = xs map f
  for (i <- ys.indices; (as, bs) = ys splitAt i) yield as ++ bs.tail
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define it like this:

```
class ShadowMapSeq[A, Repr <: Seq[A]](seq: SeqLike[A, Repr]) {
  def shadowMap[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): Iterator[That] = {
    seq.indices.iterator.map { i =>
      val b = bf(seq.asInstanceOf[Repr])
      b.sizeHint(seq.size - 1)
      b ++= (seq.take(i) ++ seq.drop(i + 1)).map(f)
      b.result
    }
  }
}
implicit def shadowMapSeq[A, Repr <: Seq[A]](seq: SeqLike[A, Repr]) = new ShadowMapSeq(seq)
```

And then use it like this:

```
scala> val v = IndexedSeq(1, 2, 3, 4)
scala> val results = v.shadowMap(_ + 1)
scala> results foreach println
Vector(3, 4, 5)
Vector(2, 4, 5)
Vector(2, 3, 5)
Vector(2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "pure functional style" you mean something like "without making reference to indices" (since you say you want to avoid `patch` and `slice`), you can do this pretty elegantly with [zippers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_%28data_structure%29). For example, here's how to write it with [Scalaz's zipper implementation](http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.4/doc.sxr/scalaz/Zipper.scala.html) (this is just a demonstration—if you want to wrap it up more nicely you can use the approach dhg gives in his answer):

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

List(1, 2, 3, 4).map(_ + 1).toZipper.map(
   _.positions.map(p => (p.lefts.reverse ++ p.rights).toList).toStream
).flatten
```

In general you're probably better off going with dhg's solution in real code, but the zipper is a handy data structure to know about, and it's a good fit for this problem.